# Google bookmarks app?

Tags: bookmarks

Is there an app for Google Bookmarks (this is distinct from Chrome bookmarks)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Google Bookmarks have been discontinued since October 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Bookmarks), in addition to software recommendations being off-topic now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Gomarks](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.androappsdev.gomarks). Looks promising.

Comment: I've used Gomarks, and it works well.

Comment: Having to enter your Google password is annoying

Answer (score 1):

Dolphin can actually sync with Google Bookmarks. Dolphin is widely used, so that's a plus in terms of trustworthiness. Searching the bookmarks isn't very nice though, but you can filter by tags