# How can I sync the bookmarks in the web browser?

Tags: sync, bookmarks

I want to open the bookmarks I saved in my PC to be seen from my cellphone's browser. So I need them synced. How can I do that, say with Nexus One?

Comment: Possible duplicate. I [answered](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/google-bookmarks-app/1437#1437) with Go Marks for that one.

Answer (score 3):

[Fennec (pre-release FireFox mobile)](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/mobile/2.0a1/releasenotes/index.html) is supposed to have bookmark synch.

I haven't tested it, as the Fennec install keeps failing on my Incredible. :-(

Comment: I've tried this and it works, but Fennec was soo slow on my Samsung Vibrant (Galaxy S) that I uninstalled it.

Comment: This is how I do my browser sync. For info Fennec is out of beta now and officially called Firefox 4 which was fully released recently. It is now much slimmer and faster than the early betas were. market.android.com/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox

Answer (score 3):

[Chrome for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) is now out of Beta, and not only does it sync your bookmarks, but also lets you open a browser tab that you have open on another device.

Comment: It doesn't quite "sync" the way I'd expect, though: the bookmarks and tabs from your desktop machine are only available to you on the phone if your phone has "sync" turned on.  Unlike, say, gmail, which makes your emails available regardless, and only requires "sync" on to catch up.

Answer (score 2):

[Transmute](http://www.gettransmute.com/android/) "will quickly and easily sync the bookmarks from the standard web browser on your Android device with Google Bookmarks." (untested)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an app from Google named Chrome2Phone : http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.google.android.apps.chrometophone.

That's a pretty good one !

Comment: Pretty sure this only lets you share one link at a time, rather than do a proper sync?

Comment: @GAThrawn yup, that's correct.  It also requires you auth your Google account with a server in eastern Europe... a bit on the scary side, IMHO

Comment: I used this frequently, as well as the firefox version of the extension, called Fox2Phone.  Sadly, the chrometophone app engine app is defunct.

Answer (score 1):

The Delicious site has an Android app, so any bookmarks you save there will be available on your phone.

Another option is to use Opera on the PC and phone, Opera Link will then sync your bookmarks.

Comment: can you link to any of these?

Comment: Opera mini my.opera.com/chooseopera/blog/2010/07/14/opera-mini-5-1-final-for-android

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/deliciousdroid/

Answer (score 1):

what about [xmarks.com](http://www.xmarks.com/about/features/bookmark_sync)?

Comment: Don't forget to mention that the xmarks/lastpass bundle also saves and syncs passwords.